# jQuery: How can I bind multiple elements of the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

I've created a div which I want to fill with a different embedded video based on which link within a series of links below that div gets clicked by a user.  Currently, the function only works only for the top link in the list.  Clicking on any of the links under the first produces no effect.  Here's the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
$('a.videoBoxLinks').bind('click',function(e){
var vidUrl = $(this).attr('href');
var vidBox = $(this).prev('.videoBox');
vidBox.html('<iframe src="' + vidUrl + '" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
e.preventDefault(); //stops the browser click event
});
});
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="videoBox">
<h1>default content to be replaced</h1>
</div>
<a class="videoBoxLinks" href="videoURL1">Test 1</a></br> <!--this one works-->
<a class="videoBoxLinks" href="videoURL2">Test 2</a> <!--this one doesn't-->
```

Comment: So if you click the second link before the first, it still does nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following code. It works for me.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="videoBox">
    <h1>
        default content to be replaced</h1>
</div>
<a class="videoBoxLinks" href="videoURL1">Test 1</a><br />
<!--this one works-->
<a class="videoBoxLinks" href="videoURL2">Test 2</a>
```

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('a.videoBoxLinks').bind('click', function (e) {
            var vidUrl = $(this).attr('href');
            //var vidBox = $(this).prev('.videoBox');
            $("#videoBox").html('<iframe src="' + vidUrl + '" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe>');                
            e.preventDefault(); //stops the browser click event
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I had earlier accepted Rahul's answer below, but when I started working on layout, I put the list of links into a table, only to discover that it was no longer working.  As it turns out, prevAll() only finds siblings - which Rahul pointed out (I forgot!).  This solution works for all elements with the target ID, which is what I need.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
var vidBox = $(this).prev('.videoBox');
```

use

```
var vidBox = $(this).prevAll('.videoBox');
```

[**`.prev`**](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) will only find the immediately preceding sibling whereas [**`.prevAll`**](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) will find all preceding siblings.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use delegate.  Bind only binds a single event, whereas delegate just adds event listeners.

That should at least get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
$('a.videoBoxLinks').bind('click',function(e){
    link = $(this);
    // if the iframe does not exists
    if ($('div.videoBox iframe').length == 0) {
        // create the iframe
        $('div.videoBox').html('<iframe width="400" height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
    }
    // set the source of the iframe
    iframe = $('div.videoBox iframe').attr('src', link.attr('href'));
    e.preventDefault(); //stops the browser click event
});
```